# Adding realationship with 2 schemas with mongoose and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I need to have some relationships between two schema. like a relationship between User and comments. This is the code i have tried.

```
const user = new Schema({
    uname:String,
    email:String,
    password:String,
    created:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

const comment = new Schema({
    user:{
        type : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : 'user'
    },
    comment:String,
    created:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

How should i save data to comment? Do i have to pass the ID of the users whose commenting? or can i pass any unique value (email or username).How to pass data and retrieve comment data?. Im quite new to NoSQL databases.

Comment: This has an example of saving refs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

you can create a key `userId` in comment's schema as string, userId will be the user's `_id` (unique id created at the time of instance creation).

for every comment instance creation a `userId` is pass so that the comment will be associate to that particular user and you can find it out (comment) by passing userId in the query.

lets say :

```
   user1 :
        _id : abc12amcne345ffc
        uname: 'hello',
        email: 'abc@gmail.com',
        password: 'acd224',
        created: somedate
```

and for comment

```
Comment : 

    userId: ' abc12amcne345ffc ',
    comment: 'hello',
    created: somedate
```

it is simple structure for start i think.